# Create and retrieve documents from IBM BPM document store using a service without any UI

Tags: websphere, business-process-management

My BPM application doesn't have any UI as it is used by an external system. The external UI will need to invoke the service(s) in BPM that can store and retrieve the documents in IBM Document Store based on some identifier like process instance.

I couldn't succeed with tw.system.findProcessInstanceByID(id).addDocument(...). Also, as the input to the BPM service is base64, how do I map it?

The other option I tried is with Content Integration Task but again how to map the attributes from the external system to the BPM service?

Also, how can I send back all the files corresponding to an id to the external application?

Any suggestions as to how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IBM Document Store that use IBM BPM, is a FileNet Express that is installed directly on the Webspehere product where live IBM BPM. You can find the route of the API of the internal Filenet in the documentation of IBM BPM.

The other why is to expose a service that use the content integration services to create (with attibutes), getProperties or getContent to enable you UI with this operations.